# Unity: Raycast Doesn't Hit Child Object's Collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a tile based game. I place towers as child objects of tiles. I want to be able to detect mouse clicks on towers but not tiles, with raycasting. Both tiles and the towers have 2d box colliders. I can detect clicks on tiles but raycast won't detect the ones on the towers. How can I solve this problem. Thanks.

Here is my code for raycasting:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            ray.origin = camera.transform.position;

            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(camera.transform.position, -Vector2.up, 50, 8);

            if (hit.collider != null && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            {
                Debug.Log(hit.collider.transform.tag);
                //Transform objectHit = hit.transform;

            }
        }
    }
```

When I mask the tiles (here layer 8) I get nothing. It seems rays never hit the towers although towers (like tiles) also have a 2d box collider.

Comment: What layer is the child object you want to detect click on?

Comment: It's on the layer 9 @Programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fishing, but isn't it possible that your child collider is hidden inside the parent colider? Raycast then  would return only the first hit. You can try `RaycastAll` as documented here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html

and loop through all hits in console to know if you are actually getting the collider or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using using a 3d ray instead of a 2d one. Maybe Camera.screenPointToRay might come in hand. Also, I would suggest you read this first: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-2d-raycast-from-mouse-to-screen.211708/

Answer (score 0):

Just restrict the raycast for specfic layers

```
//get the mask to raycast against either the player or enemy layer
 int layer_mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Player", "Enemy");
 //or this would be just player
 //int layer_mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Player");

 //or this would be player, enemy or cows!
 //int layer_mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Player","Enemy","Cows");

 //do the raycast specifying the mask
 if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, distance, layer_mask))
 {

 }
```